# How to keep scroll position independent of postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scroll

I have a regular time interval event in javascript which clicks an asp button. The application is a common chat room and I have to refresh the gridview (which is inside a panel) to check for new chats. But everytime the button is clicked and gridview is refreshed the panel scrolls up to the top (i.e., scrollTop value becomes 0). I have tried this but to no avail:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh() {
        setInterval(function () {
            var xtop = document.getElementById("Panel1").scrollTop;
            document.getElementById("Button2").click();
            document.getElementById("Panel1").scrollTop = xtop;
        }, 1000);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the scroll position between postbacks, in your `refresh()` function you can store the scroll position value in a hidden field that you put somewhere in your HTML: `<input type="hidden" id="scroll"></input>`  using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("scroll").value = document.getElementById("Panel1").scrollTop;
```

There are other options to persist data such as cookies and the ASP.NET ViewState, but a hidden field is simplest for this purpose.  You can then read this value from the hidden field upon loading the DOM and scroll the window to that position.

However, if you are posting back every second to check for new messages, you probably have a bigger problem.  This kind of functionality is better done asynchronously with AJAX.  It will need a bit of looking into as I'm not sure of your implementation here, but essentially you will use JavaScript to ask the server if there are new messages and load them from the server asynchronously, thereby eliminating the use of postbacks.

[Here is Mozilla's introduction to AJAX.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)